# What ways of vertical text centering inside a div contaner do you know?

Tags: css

What ways of vertical text centering inside a div contaner do you know?

Answer (score 1):

1. `text-align:center`;
2. `margin:0 auto;` //tag needs to have a with

Comment: Not OP, but what is the difference between 'margin: 0 auto 0 auto' and 'margin: 0 auto'?

Comment: And what about *vertical* text?

Comment: there is no difference, using margin:0 auto; is the short-hand version see: http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/

Comment: @kevin: `margin: A` becomes `margin: A A A A`. `margin: A B` becomes `margin: A B A B`. `margin: A B C` becomes `margin: A B C B`.

Answer (score 0):

1. If a single line of text, setting the line height of the div to be the height of the div.
2. If the height of the content is known, position it absolutely - top: 50%, margin-top: -(half the height of the content) pixels.